# how to make table, alter column, and insert data into it at once in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, alter

I want to send data from `HTML` to `PHP` and with `POST` and create table first with table value and alter add column with column value, and finally want to insert data into the column with data values when I send from `HTML`,
but no matter I do it keeps having error.

Here is my HTML Code.

```
<form method="post" action="table2.php">
 Table<input type="text" name="table"><br>
 Column<input type="text" name="column"><br>
 Data<input type="text" name="data"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and here is my PHP code,

```
<?php

include_once("login2.php");

$table = $_POST['table'];
$column = $_POST['column'];
$data = $_POST['data'];


$createTable = "create table ".$table."(
id int not null auto_increment, 
nickname varchar(50),
primary key(id)
)";

/*    Create Table   */

if(mysqli_query($conn, $createTable)){
echo "<br><br>";
echo "table created successfully";
$alterColumn = "alter table ".$table." add ".$column. "varchar(100)";
}else{
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "Failed to create databases";
}


/*  Alter add Column into the Table   */

if(mysqli_query($conn, $alterColumn)){
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "column created successfully";
    $insertValue = "insert into ".$table."(".$column.")values(".$data.");";
 }else{
      echo "<br><br>";
      echo "Failed to alter column";
    }

/* Insert data into the Column above  */

if(mysqli_query($conn, $insertValue)){
      echo "<br><br>";
      echo "Every process successfully done.";
}else{
      echo "<br><br>";
      echo "Failed to insert data"; 
   }
    
?>
```

Here are the errors that I have:

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\table2.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: insertValue in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\table2.php on line 41
>
> Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\table2.php on line 41

Comment: Can you write a functioning query in plain sql? Maybe start with that, and identify any discrepancies between that and your echoed query.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the alter query code

```
$alterColumn = "alter table ".$table." add ".$column. "varchar(100)";
```

change it to

```
$alterColumn = "alter table ".$table." add ".$column. " varchar(100)";
```

Added space after the `$column` variable

Comment: OH Thank you so much! haha

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach - seems to work in tests anyway. I believe it is always better to use backticks around table and column names - which also would have helped when a simple space was missing from `alter` command. The final `insert` statement required quotes around the actual data - though using prepared statements would have been a better solution.

```
<?php

    include_once("login2.php");

    $table = $_POST['table'];
    $column = $_POST['column'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    /*    Create Table   */
    $createTable = "create table `".$table."`(
        `id` int not null auto_increment, 
        `nickname` varchar(50),
        primary key(`id`)
        )";

    /* bitwise operator to test if everything is ok */
    $result = !empty( $createTable ) & mysqli_query( $conn, $createTable );
    $alterColumn = $result ? "alter table `".$table."` add `" . $column . "` varchar(100)" : false;
    echo $result ? 'Table created' : 'Failed to create table';


    /*  Alter add Column into the Table   */
    $result = !empty( $alterColumn ) & mysqli_query( $conn, $alterColumn );
    /* data needs to be quoted! */
    $insertValue = $result ? "insert into `".$table."` ( `".$column."` ) values ('".$data."');" : false;
    echo $result ? 'Column added' : 'Failed to add column';

    /* Insert data into the Column above  */
    $result = !empty( $insertValue ) & mysqli_query( $conn, $insertValue );
    echo $result ? "Every process successfully done." : "Failed to insert data";


?>
```